# Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain alphabet and numeric?

Tags: c#, nlp

I want to use the regular expression to check the string that doesn't contain alphabet or numeric for removing it.

```
Ex: "().;" => false
    "(9).;" => true
    ")+&^%" => false
    "A)%$#" => true
```

Thanks and regards,
Hien Su

Comment: Then why don't you use it?

Comment: would recommend using straight C# for this

Answer (score 2):

```
var shouldKeep = myString.Any(c=>Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Or

```
var shouldKeep = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("\\w", myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a one-liner without using regex:

```
 private static void Main()
 {
    Console.WriteLine(TestAlphaNumeric("().;"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestAlphaNumeric("(9).;"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestAlphaNumeric(")+&^%"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestAlphaNumeric("A)%$#"));
    Console.Read();
 }

 private static bool TestAlphaNumeric(string str)
 {
    return str.Any(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
 }
```

output:

> False
>
> True
>
> False
>
> True

Answer (score 1):

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string  pattern = @"(\w|\d)";
```